# How to prove $\left| a_v\cos{vx}+b_v\sin{vx} \right|^2\leq a_v^2+b_v^2$

Tags: inequality, fourier-series

My question is from the proof of corollaries of the main theorem on fourier series. How to prove $$\left| a_v\cos{vx}+b_v\sin{vx} \right|^2\leq a_v^2+b_v^2$$

Comment: In general $(aC+bS)^2 \leq (a^2+b^2)(C^2+S^2)$ and here $C^2+S^2 = 1$. This is a special case of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(a\cos x + b\sin x)^2+(b\cos x - a\sin x)^2=a^2+b^2\implies(a\cos x + b\sin x)^2\le a^2+b^2$$